# How to retrieve all elements from a table with a specific attribute from the relationship with other table in SQLALCHEMY

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLALCHEMY in a FastApi application and I have two tables that I want to list all elements from one making join and getting only a specific row from the other, the tables follow below:

```
class BranchOffice(Base):
BranchOfficeId = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, index = True, autoincrement=False)
AreaId = Column(Integer)
AreaDescription = Column(String(45))
Uf = Column(String(2))
Sellers = relationship("Seller",backref="BranchOffice")



class Seller(Base):
SellerId = Column(Integer, primary_key = True, index = True, autoincrement=False)
SellerName = Column(String(60))
OriginId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("Origin.OriginId"))
BranchOfficeId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("BranchOffice.BranchOfficeId"))
```

I've tried :
sellers = db.query(Seller, BranchOffice.AreaDescription).all()

But it produces this output:

```
[
  {
    "Seller": {
      "OriginId": 1,
      "SellerName": "teste name 1",
      "SellerId": 222,
      "BranchOfficeId": 555
    },
    "AreaDescription": "teste"
  },
  {
    "Seller": {
      "OriginId": 1,
      "SellerName": "teste name 2",
      "SellerId": 222,
      "BranchOfficeId": 555
    },
    "AreaDescription": "teste novo"
  }
]
```

I wanna "AreaDescription" inside the object Seller like this:

```
{
    "Seller": {
      "OriginId": 1,
      "SellerName": "teste name 2",
      "SellerId": 222,
      "BranchOfficeId": 555,
      "AreaDescription": "teste novo"
    },
    
  }
```

Does someone have a solution?

Comment: Since you've defined a `relationship`, you should be able to access it as `seller.BranchOffice.AreaDescription` (for each `Seller` object). In FastAPI, a neat way to do this is to define a `response_model` pydantic model `SellerResponse` with a `BranchOfficeResponse` as a field.

Comment: Thanks! I solved with another approach. But this is a good Idea too.